# Is it thread safe to read a form controls value (but not change it) without using Invoke/BeginInvoke from another thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-3.5

I know you can read a gui control from a worker thread without using Invoke/BeginInvoke because my app is doing it now.  The cross thread exception error is not being thrown and my System.Timers.Timer thread is able to read gui control values just fine (unlike this guy: [can a worker thread read a control in the GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295870/can-a-worker-thread-read-a-control-in-the-gui))

**Question 1:**  Given the cardinal rule of threads, should I be using Invoke/BeginInvoke to read form control values?  And does this make it more thread-safe?  The background to this question stems from a problem my app is having.  It seems to randomly corrupt form controls another thread is referencing. (see question 2)

**Question 2:**  I have a second thread that needs to update form control values so I Invoke/BeginInvoke to update those values.  Well this same thread needs a reference to those controls so it can update them.  It holds a list of these controls (say DataGridViewRow objects). Sometimes (not always), the DataGridViewRow reference gets "corrupt".  What I mean by corrupt, is the reference is still valid, but some of the DataGridViewRow properties are null (ex: row.Cells).  Is  this caused by question 1 or can you give me any tips on why this might be happening?

Here's some code (the last line has the problem):

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    void Timer_Elapsed(object sender)
    {
        // we're on a new thread (this function gets called every few seconds)  
        UpdateUiHelper updateUiHelper = new UpdateUiHelper(this);       

        // Is it thread-safe to step through the datagrid rows here without invoking?
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            object[] values = GetValuesFromDb();
            updateUiHelper.UpdateRowValues(row, values[0]);
        }

        // .. do other work here

        updateUiHelper.UpdateUi();
    }
}

public class UpdateUiHelper
{
    private readonly Form _form;
    private Dictionary<DataGridViewRow, object> _rows;
    private delegate void RowDelegate(DataGridViewRow row);
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public UpdateUiHelper(Form form)
    {
        _form = form;
        _rows = new Dictionary<DataGridViewRow, object>();
    }

    public void UpdateRowValues(DataGridViewRow row, object value)
    {
        if (_rows.ContainsKey(row))
            _rows[row] = value;
        else
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                _rows.Add(row, value);
            }
        }

    }

    public void UpdateUi()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _rows.Keys)
        {
            SetRowValueThreadSafe(row);               
        }
    }

    private void SetRowValueThreadSafe(DataGridViewRow row)
    {
        if (_form.InvokeRequired)
        {
            _form.Invoke(new RowDelegate(SetRowValueThreadSafe), new object[] { row });
            return;
        }

        // now we're on the UI thread
        object newValue = _rows[row];
        row.Cells[0].Value = newValue; // randomly errors here with NullReferenceException, but row is never null!
    }
```

Comment: Win32 controls must be accessed only from the thread that created them. It's therefore best to only access the control, even just for reading, from that thread, since you don't control exactly how "reading" takes place for each control. In any case, you should be synchronizing your cross-thread memory accesses in case a write happens halfway through a read.

Comment: Just because are getting away with reading a UI control from a background thread does not mean you should.  .NET only checks ownership every once in a while so yes you can get away with it you do so at your risk.  Can you just bind the control property to a regular property and read that?

Comment: I added a lock statement.  Is that good enough or do I need to add more?

Comment: Getting a lock to work is non-trivial.  The main-thread message-dispatcher would have to acquire/release the same lock in such a manner that inconsistent reads are prevented.  During normal GUI operations, thousands of messages for hundreds of different windows can get handled in a second, (and some of these are recursive SendMessage calls).  A message-dispatch lock is err.. 'very difficult' to get 100% right.  Stick with Invoke() or, preferably, BeginInvoke().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RE 1: The cardinal rule is that Windows controls must be accessed on the thread where their message pump is running.  In .NET that's the thread that is running `Application.Run`.  It's the one processing the messages and everything you do to a Windows control is a message.  So, if you send a message from another thread, the thread processing the messages could have race conditions (the message pump isn't thread-safe because that would impact performance too much, among other reasons).  Now, accessing a .NET class instance doesn't necessarily cause a message to be sent.  In those cases, yes, they can be accessed from a thread that isn't the UI thread.  What does and does not send a message or under what circumstances a single member does and doesn't send a message is not documented.  So, you're just gambling that an exception won't occur when you access a control object at all from a non UI thread.  Best practice is to always use `InvokeRequired`/`BeginInvoke`.  Anything else could change when you least expect it and if it does fail, what you did wasn't supported.

RE 2: I couldn't tell you if 1 caused 2--there really isn't enough detail.  If you're doing something with something in an unsupported way, it's reasonable to expect unexpected things to occur.

If this is a WinForms app, I would recommend using `Forms.Timer` instead. It invokes the `Tick` handler on the UI thread and you don't have to bother with `InvokeRequired`/`BeginInvoke`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and details regarding the messaging.  I changed my code to invoke when reading control values.  I had to give it a couple days before I was convinced that fixed it, but it appears it did.  One thing to be cautious of is the overuse of Invoke/BeginInvoke. Too many messages in the message queue can mean unresponsive UI - defeating the purpose of threads.

Comment: @goku_da_master Definitely; just because you're calling Invoke\BeginInvoke doesn't mean the UI can keep up with you :)